# GTM cross domain tracking

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am trying to do a cross domain GTM, but have a question. I have the GTM and GA in domain1.com  and just GTM in domain2.com. Is it possible to track variables by using just the container? or do I need a GA in both domains?

GTM in domain1.com and domain2.com

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js? 
id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-xxxx');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GTM container itself does not track anything. You need GA on both domains. However, as you are using the same container on both sites you can use the same Analytics tag within the container - you do not need a tag per domain, and you do not need Analytics code outside your container (which might be what you are actually asking).

In your GA settings variable (or in your GTM Google Analytics tag, if you have "enable override settings variable" checked) go to the advanced settings, look for cross domain tracking and enter a comma separated list of your domains in the "autolink domains" field ([documentation here](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6164469?hl=en)). This will decorate hrefs and forms automatically with the linker parameter (and set Analytics to use the value from the parameter). This does not cover a few edge cases (like redirects via Javascript), but usually it's good enough.

Answer (score -1):

In a cross-domain setup where you have Google Tag Manager (GTM) and Google Analytics (GA) implemented on different domains, you can still track variables and send data to GA using just the GTM container. You don't necessarily need to have GA implemented on both domains.

Here's how you can achieve this:

Set up Cross-Domain Tracking in Google Analytics:

In your GA property settings, configure cross-domain tracking by specifying the domains you want to track as referrals to each other. This will allow GA to properly attribute sessions and user behavior across the domains.
Follow the steps provided by Google Analytics to set up cross-domain tracking. This typically involves configuring the linker parameter and adding the appropriate GA tracking code to your website.
Implement Google Tag Manager (GTM) on both domains:

Install and configure GTM on both domain1.com and domain2.com.
Create a GTM container on each domain and obtain the respective container IDs.
Configure GTM Variables and Tags:

Within the GTM container on domain1.com, set up variables to capture the necessary data you want to track. These variables can include pageviews, events, or custom dimensions.
Create tags in GTM to send the captured data to GA. Configure the tags to trigger based on user interactions or pageview events.
Configure Cross-Domain Tracking in GTM:

In the GTM container on domain1.com, configure the GA tags to enable cross-domain tracking. This can typically be done by setting the allow Linker parameter to true within the GA configuration tag.
Configure the Auto Link Domains variable in GTM to include both domain1.com and domain2.com. This ensures that the linker parameter is appended to the appropriate links between the domains.
Publish the GTM Container:

Once you have set up the necessary variables, tags, and cross-domain tracking configurations in the GTM container on domain1.com, publish the container to make it live.
By following these steps, you can track variables using GTM and send the data to GA, even if GA is implemented only on domain1.com. The cross-domain tracking configuration in GA and GTM allows you to properly attribute user behavior across the domains, providing a comprehensive view of your website analytics.